# Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined in composition component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm working on a project with `Nextjs13` with `App` router I created a `composition button` with two child components the title and icon component.
But I got this error

```
Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
```

button component

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import ButtonTitle from "./buttonTitle";
import { ButtonProps } from "./buttonProps";
import ButtonIcon from "./buttonIcon";

const Button = ({ children }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <motion.button className="btn btn-outlined">{children}</motion.button>;
};

export default Button;

Button.Title = ButtonTitle;
Button.Icon = ButtonIcon;
```

button title

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { ButtonProps } from "./buttonProps";

const ButtonTitle = ({ children }: ButtonProps) => {
  return <span className="text-slate-50">{children}</span>;
};

export default ButtonTitle;
```

and also the button icon component like button title.

and I call in the header component like this

```
import { Logo } from "@/public";
import Image from "@/app/components/ui/image/image";
import React from "react";
import HeaderNav from "./nav/nav";
import Button from "@/app/components/ui/button/button";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 max-w-[1440px] mx-auto flex-row-center max-h-[88px] px-2 py-6 backdrop-blur-[15px] bg-[rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.20)]">
      <div className="flex-row-between w-full">
        {/*logo */}
        <Image
          _css="h-[72px] w-[72px]"
          alt="logo"
          title="logo"
          src={Logo}
        />

        {/* header menu links */}
        <HeaderNav />

        <Button>
          <Button.Title>Reservation</Button.Title>
        </Button>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```